# bash command color for IRB

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, ruby, bashrc

Is there a way to change the command and prompt color in IRB/rails console different from their outputs?

As of now I have this in my bashrc file

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[00;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$\[\033[00;34m\] '

trap '[[ -t 1 ]] && tput sgr0' DEBUG
```

[image]

As of now, the console commands dont take the bashrc setting colors of command and prompt and it becomes tough to read when console grows bigger.

Any way to change this as well?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `pry` ruby console instead of default `irb`, because `pry` has built-in syntax-coloring, indentation support. Installation is pretty simple

```
gem install pry
```

There are other tools too, which can be used with `irb` to enhance it's functionality. One such tool is

- [`irbtools`](https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools) - https://github.com/janlelis/irbtools

  1. Install it with `gem install irbtools`
  2. After installation, put this line in `~/.irbrc` (if there is no such file, create one) `require 'irbtools'`. This will give you some fancy colors in `irb`.
- [`wirb`](https://github.com/janlelis/wirb/) - https://github.com/janlelis/wirb/
- [`fancy_irb`](https://github.com/janlelis/fancy_irb) - https://github.com/janlelis/fancy_irb

The other two gems installation procedure are similar. Check their github READMEs.

---

Here is a screenshot of the `pry` console.

[image: A screenshot of pry console]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a permanent solution but makes it easy.

In IRB, instead of using `puts` or `pp`, one can use the [Ruby `ap`](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print)

It adds color and structure to output. Really nice.

[image]

But I wish IRB had something built-in to handle all use cases.